PIP downloading again package already installed
I am trying to install tsai. When doing so, PIP tries to download PyTorch:
Collecting torch<1.14,>=1.7.0 (from tsai==0.3.5)

However, I already have a version that matches 1.7 < my version < 1.14. See:
$ pip list | grep torch
torch                         1.8.1

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

This does seem like a bug in pip. Consider reporting this there. It looks like pip is unable to recognize that the currently installed torch==1.8.1 wheel is compatible with Python 3.8.
With uv pip install tsai==0.3.5, torch is not being fetched again.

My solution was to install it with --no-dependecies flag and then install the packages independently. Once I installed a package I got the red message of PIP telling me all things that go wrong. And manually installed every package until it works :)

install from source the guide is in the readme of tsai github:
https://github.com/timeseriesAI/tsai/#installation
Installation
If you plan to develop tsai yourself, or want to be on the cutting edge, you can use an editable install. First install PyTorch, and then:
git clone https://github.com/timeseriesAI/tsai

pip install -e "tsai[dev]"

Note: starting with tsai 0.3.0 tsai will only install hard dependencies. Other soft dependencies (which are only required for selected tasks) will not be installed by default (this is the recommended approach. If you require any of the dependencies that is not installed, tsai will ask you to install it when necessary). If you still want to install tsai with all its dependencies you can do it by running:
pip install tsai[extras]

Conda install
You can also install tsai using conda (note that if you replace conda with mamba the install process will be much faster and more reliable):
conda install -c timeseriesai tsai


I mean, I did not expected to develop tsai. My question is why it tried to update my torch version. It tries to download 1.13, and then it crashed because I have a python version not compatible with torch 1.13. However, I have 1.8 that looks Ok from my point of view.

Well, you don't need to develop tsai those message I answer above is just copied from the github readme. I'm just trying to show you alternative way that you can download from source and use it since using pip directly doesn't work for you, sorry if it doesn't help.

But it is still using pip, I think I will still have the error
